# Alamofire clear all cookies

Tags: ios, swift, cookies, authentication, alamofire

I need the user to be able to log out. When they log in now, a cookie gets saved automatically, that works fine. But I want to clear all cookies.

```
NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().removeAllCachedResponses()
```

This does not work

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can remove all the cookies specifically stored for an URL like this (Swift 3):

```
let cstorage = HTTPCookieStorage.shared
if let cookies = cstorage.cookies(for: url) {
    for cookie in cookies {
        cstorage.deleteCookie(cookie)
    }
}
```

Comment: There is also simpler method to remove all cookies for all urls: `HTTPCookieStorage.shared.removeCookies(since: Date.distantPast)`